# ASPNet Core post list of parent objects and childs

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-core-mvc

this is not exactly my code but for simplicity purpose it would be the same, let's say I have these classes:

```
public class Course
{
public int CourseId;
public string CourseName;
public List<Question> Questions;
}

public class Question
{
public int QuestionId;
public string QuestionDescription;
public List<Answer> Answers;
}

public class Answer
{
public int AnswerId;
public string AnswerDescription;
public bool Selected;
}
```

I need to post from a form all of the questions and answers...

```
  @model Course
        <form action="MyPostMethod">
        @{
    foreach(var question in Model.Questions)
{
<div>
<h3>@question.QuestionDescription</h3>
</div>
@{
foreach(var answer in question.Answers)
{
<input type="radio" id=@answer.AnswerId name="@answer.AnswerId"/>
<label for="@answer.AnswerId">@answer.AnswerDescription</label>
}
}
}
    }
<input type=submit value="Submit"/>
        </form>
```

How can I post from the .cshtml page all of the data to my ActionResult in the controller?
The idea in my controller would be something like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult MyPostMethod(List<Question> questions)
{
//some more code
}
```

How should I structure in the .cshtml page the data in order to post to my controller a list of the `Questions` with their related 'Answers' to my controller?

Answer (score 0):

Having inputs within the `Questions` loop like:

```
<input type="hidden" name="questions[@questionsCounter].QuestionId" value="@question.QuestionId" />
```

and within the `Answers` loop like:

```
<input type="hidden" name="questions[@questionsCounter].Answers[@answersCounter].AnswerId" value="@answer.AnswerId" />
```

did it